# how to get language of device with cordova angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, globalization

i want to include the `navigator.globalization` so i use this tutorial [enter link description here](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/08/internationalization-localization-ionicframework-angular-translate/)

this code:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $translate) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            if(typeof navigator.globalization !== "undefined") {
                navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(function(language) {
                    $translate.use((language.value).split("-")[0]).then(function(data) {
                        alert("SUCCESS -> " + data);
                    }, function(error) {
                        alert("ERROR -> " + error);
                    });
                }, null);
            }
        });
```

my problem ,this code the alert is not displayed

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Some solution? Same problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it just with

```
window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
```

Comment: i don't understand @Del

Comment: Sorry, I missuderstood the question. This answer is to get the language of the device / user without using the plugin. I leave this here in case they help you

Answer (score 0):

First check the result of

```
if(typeof navigator.globalization !== "undefined") {
```

If its false, the rest of the code will be skipped, because you dont have the plugin.

To get the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-globalization
```

Comment: no ,look please ( cordova plugin list
com.atuhi.externalkeyboard 0.0.1 "External Keyboard"
com.raananw.imageResizerTT 0.1.3 "ImageResizer"
com.synconset.imagepicker 1.0.7 "ImagePicker"
cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.2.0 "ActionSheet"
cordova-plugin-calendar 4.4.5 "Calendar"
cordova-plugin-camera 1.2.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2-dev "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 1.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.2 "Globalization"

Comment: Try: 

`navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
    function (language) {alert('language: ' + language.value + '\n');},
    function () {alert('Error getting language\n');}
);`

[The github doc](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization)

Comment: !JavaScript ERROR: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage')

Comment: You use device or browser to test?
Some of the cordova plugins wont work in browser, you need to run the app on device

Comment: i run the app on real device